# Why are the 2 <select> elements that are being appended to my form not looking the same as the first 2 fixed in my Form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML form that gets company information.

In that form, I have 2 `<select multiple>` elements (one for company countries and one for sectors) on which I used JQuery and Bootstrap to give them a nice style and to allow the user to choose multiple options in an easier manner.

**The Problem:** When the user clicks "Add Company Button" to add a new company section to the form, the appended `<select multiple>` elements are not being styled the same way.
The difference isn't between the first two select fields, it is rather between the first 2 select fields and the pairs that get added when you click 'Add Company'. The first two are appearing how I want them (2 rectangular boxes in which the user clicks on multiple options from the dropdown), while the others are appearing like an unstyled  dropdown where you have to press Ctrl+click on the options you want to select

**Please note that I removed the CSS and other parts of the page to keep things simple. Also in the appended section, I removed some options to stay within the character limit of this post**

The code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mul-select").select2({
    placeholder: "Select Company Sectors", //placeholder
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: ['/', ',', ';', " "]
  });
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mul-select.countries").select2({
    placeholder: "Company's Country Locations", //placeholder
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: ['/', ',', ';', " "]
  });
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn", function() {
    var index = $(".company-info").find(".company-info-row").length + 1;
    $(".company-info").append(`
            <div class="added company-info-row" style="margin:5% 0 0 0;">
  <div class="company-data" style="padding:1% 4%;">
    <div>
      <select name="addedCompany[${index}][sectors][]" id="accountSector_${index}" class="dropdown mul-select" multiple="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <option value="Advertising">Advertising</option>
        <option value="Aerospace">Aerospace</option>
        <option value="Agriculture">Agriculture</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select name="addedCompany[${index}][countries][]" id="additionalAccountLocations_${index}" class="dropdown mul-select countries" multiple="true">
        <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="add_del_btn_outer_comp" style="margin:0 4% 0 4%;">
    <button class="add_new_frm_field_btn">
      <img src="add-icon.png" alt="Add Company Button">
    </button>
    <button class="remove_node_btn_frm_field" disabled>
      <img src="remove-icon.png" alt="Remove Company Button">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
        `);
    $(".company-info").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field:not(:first)").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".company-info").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field").first().prop("disabled", true);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  //===== delete the form feed row
  $("body").on("click", ".remove_node_btn_frm_field", function() {
    $(this).closest(".company-info-row").remove();
    console.log("success");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css">
  <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login-box">
    <div class="company-info">
      <div class="company-info-row">
        <div class="company-data" style="padding:1% 4%;">
          <div>
            <select name="company[sectors][]" id="accountSector" class="dropdown mul-select" multiple>
              <option value="Advertising">Advertising</option>
              <option value="Aerospace">Aerospace</option>
              <option value="Agriculture">Agriculture</option>
              <option value="Apparel &amp; Accessories">Apparel &amp; Accessories</option>
              <option value="Architecture">Architecture</option>
              <option value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
              <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
              <option value="Biotechnology">Biotechnology</option>
              <option value="Building Materials &amp; Equipment">Building Materials &amp; Equipment</option>
              <option value="Chemical">Chemical</option>
              <option value="Computer">Computer</option>
              <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
              <option value="Consulting">Consulting</option>
              <option value="Creative">Creative</option>
              <option value="Culture">Culture</option>
              <option value="Defense">Defense</option>
              <option value="Education">Education</option>
              <option value="Electric Power">Electric Power</option>
              <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
              <option value="Energy">Energy</option>
              <option value="Entertainment &amp; Leisure">Entertainment &amp; Leisure</option>
              <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
              <option value="Food &amp; Beverage">Food &amp; Beverage</option>
              <option value="Grocery">Grocery</option>
              <option value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option>
              <option value="Hospitality">Hospitality</option>
              <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
              <option value="Legal">Legal</option>
              <option value="Manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
              <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
              <option value="Mass Media">Mass Media</option>
              <option value="Mining">Mining</option>
              <option value="Music">Music</option>
              <option value="Petroleum">Petroleum</option>
              <option value="Publishing">Publishing</option>
              <option value="Real Estate">Real Estate</option>
              <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
              <option value="Service">Service</option>
              <option value="Shipping">Shipping</option>
              <option value="Software">Software</option>
              <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
              <option value="Support">Support</option>
              <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
              <option value="Telecommunications">Telecommunications</option>
              <option value="Television">Television</option>
              <option value="Testing, Inspection &amp; Certification">Testing, Inspection &amp; Certification</option>
              <option value="Transportation">Transportation</option>
              <option value="Travel">Travel</option>
              <option value="Venture Capital">Venture Capital</option>
              <option value="Water">Water</option>
              <option value="Wholesale">Wholesale</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <select name="company[countries][]" id="additionalAccountLocations" class="dropdown mul-select countries" multiple>
              <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
              <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
              <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
              <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
              <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
              <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
              <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
              <option value="Antigua & Barbuda">Antigua & Barbuda</option>
              <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
              <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
              <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
              <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
              <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
              <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
              <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
              <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
              <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
              <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
              <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
              <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
              <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
              <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
              <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
              <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
              <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
              <option value="Bonaire">Bonaire</option>
              <option value="Bosnia & Herzegovina">Bosnia & Herzegovina</option>
              <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
              <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
              <option value="British Indian Ocean Ter">British Indian Ocean Ter</option>
              <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
              <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
              <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
              <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
              <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
              <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
              <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
              <option value="Canary Islands">Canary Islands</option>
              <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
              <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
              <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
              <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
              <option value="Channel Islands">Channel Islands</option>
              <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
              <option value="China">China</option>
              <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
              <option value="Cocos Island">Cocos Island</option>
              <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
              <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
              <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
              <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
              <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
              <option value="Cote DIvoire">Cote DIvoire</option>
              <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
              <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
              <option value="Curaco">Curacao</option>
              <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
              <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
              <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
              <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
              <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
              <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
              <option value="East Timor">East Timor</option>
              <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
              <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
              <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
              <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
              <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
              <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
              <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
              <option value="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
              <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
              <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
              <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
              <option value="France">France</option>
              <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
              <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
              <option value="French Southern Ter">French Southern Ter</option>
              <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
              <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
              <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
              <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
              <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
              <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
              <option value="Great Britain">Great Britain</option>
              <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
              <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
              <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
              <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
              <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
              <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
              <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
              <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
              <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
              <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
              <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
              <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
              <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
              <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
              <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
              <option value="India">India</option>
              <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
              <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
              <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
              <option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
              <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
              <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
              <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
              <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
              <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
              <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
              <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
              <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
              <option value="Korea North">Korea North</option>
              <option value="Korea Sout">Korea South</option>
              <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
              <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
              <option value="Laos">Laos</option>
              <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
              <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
              <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
              <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
              <option value="Libya">Libya</option>
              <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
              <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
              <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
              <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
              <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
              <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
              <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
              <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
              <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
              <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
              <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
              <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
              <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
              <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
              <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
              <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
              <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
              <option value="Midway Islands">Midway Islands</option>
              <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
              <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
              <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
              <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
              <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
              <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
              <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
              <option value="Nambia">Nambia</option>
              <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
              <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
              <option value="Netherland Antilles">Netherland Antilles</option>
              <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands (Holland, Europe)</option>
              <option value="Nevis">Nevis</option>
              <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
              <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
              <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
              <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
              <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
              <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
              <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
              <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
              <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
              <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
              <option value="Palau Island">Palau Island</option>
              <option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
              <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
              <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
              <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
              <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
              <option value="Phillipines">Philippines</option>
              <option value="Pitcairn Island">Pitcairn Island</option>
              <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
              <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
              <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
              <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
              <option value="Republic of Montenegro">Republic of Montenegro</option>
              <option value="Republic of Serbia">Republic of Serbia</option>
              <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
              <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
              <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
              <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
              <option value="St Barthelemy">St Barthelemy</option>
              <option value="St Eustatius">St Eustatius</option>
              <option value="St Helena">St Helena</option>
              <option value="St Kitts-Nevis">St Kitts-Nevis</option>
              <option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option>
              <option value="St Maarten">St Maarten</option>
              <option value="St Pierre & Miquelon">St Pierre & Miquelon</option>
              <option value="St Vincent & Grenadines">St Vincent & Grenadines</option>
              <option value="Saipan">Saipan</option>
              <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
              <option value="Samoa American">Samoa American</option>
              <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
              <option value="Sao Tome & Principe">Sao Tome & Principe</option>
              <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
              <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
              <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
              <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
              <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
              <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
              <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
              <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
              <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
              <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
              <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
              <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
              <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
              <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
              <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
              <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
              <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
              <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
              <option value="Tahiti">Tahiti</option>
              <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
              <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
              <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
              <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
              <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
              <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
              <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
              <option value="Trinidad & Tobago">Trinidad & Tobago</option>
              <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
              <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
              <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
              <option value="Turks & Caicos Is">Turks & Caicos Is</option>
              <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
              <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
              <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
              <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
              <option value="United Arab Erimates">United Arab Emirates</option>
              <option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
              <option value="Uraguay">Uruguay</option>
              <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
              <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
              <option value="Vatican City State">Vatican City State</option>
              <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
              <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
              <option value="Virgin Islands (Brit)">Virgin Islands (Brit)</option>
              <option value="Virgin Islands (USA)">Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
              <option value="Wake Island">Wake Island</option>
              <option value="Wallis & Futana Is">Wallis & Futana Is</option>
              <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
              <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
              <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
              <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="add_del_btn_outer_comp" style="margin:0 4% 0 4%;">
          <button class="add_new_frm_field_btn">
              <img src="add-icon.png" alt="Add Company Button">
            </button>
          <button class="remove_node_btn_frm_field" disabled>
              <img src="remove-icon.png" alt="Remove Company Button">
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help in making them appear and function in the same way is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

***My Fiddle***: https://jsfiddle.net/30jwqfc5/

Comment: I can't see any styling differences between the two select fields. What exactly looks different for You?

Comment: The difference isn't between the two select fields, it is rather between the first 2 select fields and the pairs that get added when you click 'Add Company'. The first two are appearing how I want them (2 rectangular boxes in which the user clicks on multiple options from the dropdown), while the others are appearing like an unstyled <select> dropdown where you have to press Ctrl+click on the options you want to select

Comment: I suggest You explain that in your question. Also I still can't see that difference (after clicking "Add Company" twice). You should also add, with which browsers (and maybe browserversions) You tested your code. I used firefox and chromium.

Comment: Okay I mentioned some extra details, as for the browser I am using Firefox and Chrome (both most updated versions). Just for clarification, you're saying the appended select boxes are appearing like the first two?

Comment: Yes, exaclty, like any boxes added afterwards. I'm using firefox 94.0.1 and chromium  95.0.4638.69 .

Comment: Ah, wait a moment, that's incorrect. I just didn't recognice them at first. Ok, you're right, they are different.

Comment: Ok, seems to be a bootstrap issue. Probably bootstrap is only executed on html existing directly after page load. Sorry, I can't help with that.

Comment: No worries man thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two select elements are instance of select2 and the later element is native html select. You need to instantiate select2 for the dynamically generated select elements after hitting the add company button, inside the click handler,
`$('.mul-select').select2();`

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vpof3ab5/

Comment: Thanks a lot! But one more thing why are the placeholders being erased now when the buttons are clicked?

Comment: when you are calling select2 you need to pass the options object like you do initially, updated my answer in the fiddle, check it out now. https://jsfiddle.net/ty7zfoL4/